# Connecting derby with .net c# through ibm db2 driver

Tags: c#, .net, db2, derby

I'm trying to connect derby database with C# application through IBM DB2.

At first I've installed IBM Data Server Driver Package, which, according to the documentation given in the following url as

[http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0410ng/index.html.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0410ng/index.html)

Then I installed IBM Data Server Client, which has this dll in "bin" directory, which I added to system path. and followed every steps as per that document

but i am getting error as

```
{System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [08001] [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "xx.xx.xx.xx".  Communication function detecting the error: "selectForRecvTimeout".  Protocol specific error code(s): "0", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001
```

and error stack trace as

```
 at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle..ctor(OdbcConnection connection, OdbcConnectionString constr, OdbcEnvironmentHandle environmentHandle)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen..ctor(OdbcConnection outerConnection, OdbcConnectionString connectionOptions)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open()
```

waiting for your valuable responses and comments!!!!!!!!.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, you realize that the DeveloperWorks article you reference is 10 years old, right? That version of the IBM ADO.Net software was only able to access very old versions of the Derby database, versions 10.0 through 10.2 I believe.

You don't mention what version of Derby you're trying to run, but unless it is a VERY old version you're not going to be able to use this technique.

Comment: Thanks for your post ..i just want to know whether is any possible way to do it..or else we need to proceed with any alternative